# Using Laravel Sail with a separate testing database

Tags: mysql, docker, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel Sail as my development environment.  According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#mysql),

> when the MySQL container is starting, it will ensure a database exists whose name matches the value of your DB_DATABASE environment variable.

This works perfectly for my development environment, but not so much when it comes to testing since my `.env.testing` defines a separate database, and it seems this database does not get created - when I `sail mysql` into the container and run `show databases;` it is not listed.  As a result, running `sail test` fails every test where the database is concerned.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ...
```

My `.env` file contains this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dev
```

My `.env.testing` file contains this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
```

`DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` are the same in both files.

How can I create this database so that it's available when running `sail test`?

EDIT:

As I dug through the [repository code](https://github.com/laravel/sail) I found that the database is being created when the `mysql` container image is built, but [it doesn't look like there's an option for creating multiple databases](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/).

> `MYSQL_DATABASE`
> This variable is optional and allows you to specify the name of a database to be created on image startup. If a user/password was supplied (see below) then that user will be granted superuser access (corresponding to GRANT ALL) to this database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following to `docker-compose.yml` under the `services:` key and set your host in `.env.testing` to `mysql_test`:

```
  mysql_test:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${DB_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${DB_USERNAME}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    networks:
      - sail
```

Comment: I have tried this however the bit I am not sure about it loading in the .env.testing var?

It seems docker-compose.yml just takes the .env vars so the the sql_test db does not actually take the vars defined in env.testing to set it up right?

Comment: .env.testing is used when you run `sail test` to tell your app which database to connect to

Comment: @DeanCollins Right, the `.env` file is being loaded and that's what defines `${DB_DATABASE}`. You can hard-code the database name into the `mysql_test` container config, or have them use the same database name (which is fine, since they're different containers).

Comment: Solution is nice and simple but not work in my case.
I make sail build --no-cache with mysql_test but after all when I go sail mysql -> show databases; it shows just one database - not two that I expected.

Comment: in your .env.testing, make sure to set DB_HOST=mysql_test, Docker Compose uses the service name as the host name for networking.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create the `test` database alongside the original `dev` database on the existing mysql container:

```
sail mysql

mysql> CREATE DATABASE test;
```

I have not tested this using mysql but the same process works on postgres:

```
sail psql

dev=# CREATE DATABASE test;
```

Comment: I get "ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'sail'@'%' to database 'test'".

Comment: @gre_gor, as per the documentation, the default user is "root", not "sail". 

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#mysql

Comment: @EduardoChongkan Not on 8.x

Comment: well, it is the same for all versions.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** It gets created by default by **"./docker/mysql/create-testing-database.sh"**

Inside the **docker-compose.yml**, in the **mysql->volumes** section, you should see the following:

[image]

```
volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './docker/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
```

---

The settings in **.env.testing** are not for telling sail which name to use to create the DB, but rather to tell sail what DB it needs to use when running the tests ( it needs to be set to "testing" in order to match the default schema created by the SH script. )